# Align div to bottom without breaking layout

Tags: html, css

I want to align the bars to the bottom here: http://jsfiddle.net/7vdLV/67/

I tried using the following trick:

```
  .graph { position: relative; }
  .weekbar { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

However it breaks the graph, can anyone tell me how I should do it please in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution:

apply

```
.weekbar{
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 top:50%; // height of biggest bar
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7vdLV/93/)

Or if ancient browser support is not a big deal you can make use of the `::before` element as follows:

```
.graph::before{
 content:"";
 display:block;
 height:50%; // height of the biggest bar 
}
.weekbar{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7vdLV/90/)

Comment: I think he also wants the bars to be bottom-aligned... to remain within the grey div.

Answer (score 4):

Tweaked the HTML a bit as well as the CSS and got this: http://jsfiddle.net/7vdLV/74/

```
<div class="graph">
    <div class="weekbar"><div style="height: 10%;"></div></div>
    <div class="weekbar"><div style="height: 20%;"></div></div>
    <div class="weekbar"><div style="height: 30%;"></div></div>
    <div class="weekbar"><div style="height: 40%;"></div></div>
</div>
```

As TylerH pointed out inline styles are considered bad practice so you would be better replacing them with classes i.e.

```
<div class="graph">
    <div class="weekbar"><div class="h10"></div></div>
    <div class="weekbar"><div class="h20"></div></div>
    <div class="weekbar"><div class="h30"></div></div>
    <div class="weekbar"><div class="h40"></div></div>
</div>

.h10 {
    height: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Downvote; not only is this not even the same content as OP, but you're using in-line styles, which is bad practice, especially for an answer.

Comment: @TylerH OP's original JSFiddle uses inline styles

Comment: @TylerH - The OP's version had the same inline styles. Obviously easily changeable to a class if he doesn't want to keep them inline. It's his code.

Comment: @BillyMoat If you edit your post (perhaps to mention that inline styles are a bad thing and why), I will change my vote. As of now it's locked in until an edit.

Comment: I've amended my post to show another option for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Try transform:

```
-moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
-o-transform: scaleY(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
transform: scaleY(-1);
filter: FlipV;
-ms-filter: "FlipV";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4A2h/1/

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the .graph class with the following code

```
.graph {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #eaeaea;
 -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
 -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
 -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
 transform: scaleY(-1);
 filter: FlipH;
 -ms-filter: "FlipH";   
}
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1):

Make these edits to your CSS:

```
.graph { position:relative; }
.weekbar { position: relative; top: 100%; left: 0; }
```

Is this what you were looking to do?
http://jsfiddle.net/4HEEk/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:relative;` for the parent and `position:relative;` also for the child and calculate the `top` value by this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parentHeight = $('.graph').height();
    $('.weekbar').each(function() {
        var height = parentHeight - $(this).height();
        $(this).css('top',height*100/parentHeight + '%');
    });
});
```

Here is a [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vdLV/92/)

Answer (score 0):

I would change `float` for `display:inline-block;` then set an "invisible" resetter `div` at the start of your graph to make sure all the elements start from the bottom (rather from the bottom of the tallest line.

```
.weekbar {
    width: 3.1%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
}
.resetter{
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    width:0;
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vdLV/73/).

Also on a note about inline style usage (dont do it!). If you know that you have a discrete number of heights (ie. in your example they are all multiples of 10) i would suggest creating classes for them.